# tsfresh rolling window fails with IndexError

Tags: python, time-series, forecasting, feature-extraction, tsfresh

I am trying to extract the rolling (sliding window) features using `tsfresh 1.19` in `python 3.8.13` on Mac M1, locally and it doesn't work producing this error: **IndexError: cannot do a non-empty take from an empty axes**. Even replicating the example from the [documentation](https://tsfresh.readthedocs.io/en/latest/text/forecasting.html#the-rolling-mechanism)  gives me the same error. Here is the code that I am getting from documentation, to my understanding:

```
from tsfresh.utilities.dataframe_functions import roll_time_series 
from tsfresh import extract_features

df = pd.DataFrame({
   "id": [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2],
   "time": [1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 9],
   "x": [1, 2, 3, 4, 10, 11],
   "y": [5, 6, 7, 8, 12, 13],
})

df_rolled = roll_time_series(df, column_id="id", column_sort="time")

df_features = extract_features(df_rolled, column_id="id", column_sort="time")
```

the `df_rolled` data frame gets created with no issues and looks like this:

| id | time | x | y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| (1, 1) | 1 | 1 | 5 |
| (1, 2) | 1 | 1 | 5 |
| (1, 2) | 2 | 2 | 5 |
| (1, 3) | 1 | 1 | 5 |
| (1, 3) | 2 | 2 | 6 |
| (1, 3) | 3 | 3 | 7 |

...

**but** the `extract_features()` function produces the error `IndexError: cannot do a non-empty take from an empty axes.` I read somewhere that there maybe dependency issues and library version mismatches so I tried to create a new environment only using Conda packages, and then another one using conda and pip to make sure no dependency issues is are there. in both of them, all packages seem to be installed with correct versions as suggested [here](https://libraries.io/pypi/tsfresh/0.19.0/tree) but the problem persists. I also played with column data types and indexes but so far nothing helped.  Can anyone with some experience with the library help me get through this please :)

Also, worth noting that running the same code on AWS SageMaker with the standard `python3.8_tensorflow` kernel works with no error.

Error message:

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    RemoteTraceback                           Traceback (most recent call last)
    RemoteTraceback: 
    """
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Users/.../lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 125, in worker
        result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
      File "/Users/.../lib/python3.8/site-packages/tsfresh/utilities/distribution.py", line 43, in _function_with_partly_reduce
        results = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(results))
      File "/Users/.../lib/python3.8/site-packages/tsfresh/utilities/distribution.py", line 42, in <genexpr>
        results = (map_function(chunk, **kwargs) for chunk in chunk_list)
      File "/Users/.../lib/python3.8/site-packages/tsfresh/feature_extraction/extraction.py", line 386, in _do_extraction_on_chunk
        return list(_f())
      File "/Users/.../lib/python3.8/site-packages/tsfresh/feature_extraction/extraction.py", line 364, in _f
        result = func(x, param=parameter_list)
      File "/Users/.../lib/python3.8/site-packages/tsfresh/feature_extraction/feature_calculators.py", line 2103, in friedrich_coefficients
        calculated[m][r] = _estimate_friedrich_coefficients(x, m, r)
      File "/Users/.../lib/python3.8/site-packages/tsfresh/feature_extraction/feature_calculators.py", line 152, in _estimate_friedrich_coefficients
        df["quantiles"] = pd.qcut(df.signal, r)
      File "/Users/.../lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/tile.py", line 377, in qcut
        bins = np.quantile(x_np, quantiles)
      File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 180, in quantile
      File "/Users/.../lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 4412, in quantile
        return _quantile_unchecked(
      File "/Users/.../lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 4424, in _quantile_unchecked
        r, k = _ureduce(a,
      File "/Users/.../lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 3725, in _ureduce
        r = func(a, **kwargs)
      File "/Users/.../lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 4593, in _quantile_ureduce_func
        result = _quantile(arr,
      File "/Users/.../lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 4704, in _quantile
        previous = np.take(arr, previous_indexes, axis=DATA_AXIS)
      File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 180, in take
      File "/Users/.../lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 190, in take
        return _wrapfunc(a, 'take', indices, axis=axis, out=out, mode=mode)
      File "/Users/.../lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 57, in _wrapfunc
        return bound(*args, **kwds)
    IndexError: cannot do a non-empty take from an empty axes.
    """
    
    The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
    
    IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
    Input In [19], in <cell line: 15>()
         12 df_rolled = roll_time_series(df, column_id="id", column_sort="time")
         13 df_rolled.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
    ---> 15 df_features = extract_features(df_rolled, column_id="id", column_sort="time")
File ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/p38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tsfresh/feature_extraction/extraction.py:164, in extract_features(timeseries_container, default_fc_parameters, kind_to_fc_parameters, column_id, column_sort, column_kind, column_value, chunksize, n_jobs, show_warnings, disable_progressbar, impute_function, profile, profiling_filename, profiling_sorting, distributor, pivot)
    161 else:
    162     warnings.simplefilter("default")
--> 164 result = _do_extraction(
    165     df=timeseries_container,
    166     column_id=column_id,
    167     column_value=column_value,
    168     column_kind=column_kind,
    169     column_sort=column_sort,
    170     n_jobs=n_jobs,
    171     chunk_size=chunksize,
    172     disable_progressbar=disable_progressbar,
    173     show_warnings=show_warnings,
    174     default_fc_parameters=default_fc_parameters,
    175     kind_to_fc_parameters=kind_to_fc_parameters,
    176     distributor=distributor,
    177     pivot=pivot,
    178 )
    180 # Impute the result if requested
    181 if impute_function is not None:

File ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/p38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tsfresh/feature_extraction/extraction.py:294, in _do_extraction(df, column_id, column_value, column_kind, column_sort, default_fc_parameters, kind_to_fc_parameters, n_jobs, chunk_size, disable_progressbar, show_warnings, distributor, pivot)
    286     raise ValueError("the passed distributor is not an DistributorBaseClass object")
    288 kwargs = dict(
    289     default_fc_parameters=default_fc_parameters,
    290     kind_to_fc_parameters=kind_to_fc_parameters,
    291     show_warnings=show_warnings,
    292 )
--> 294 result = distributor.map_reduce(
    295     _do_extraction_on_chunk,
    296     data=data,
    297     chunk_size=chunk_size,
    298     function_kwargs=kwargs,
    299 )
    301 if not pivot:
    302     return result

File ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/p38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tsfresh/utilities/distribution.py:241, in IterableDistributorBaseClass.map_reduce(self, map_function, data, function_kwargs, chunk_size, data_length)
    234 else:
    235     result = (
    236         self.distribute(
    237             _function_with_partly_reduce, chunk_generator, map_kwargs
    238         ),
    239     )
--> 241 result = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(result))
    243 self.close()
    245 return result

File ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/p38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tqdm/std.py:1195, in tqdm.__iter__(self)
   1192 time = self._time
   1194 try:
-> 1195     for obj in iterable:
   1196         yield obj
   1197         # Update and possibly print the progressbar.
   1198         # Note: does not call self.update(1) for speed optimisation.

File ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/p38/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/pool.py:868, in IMapIterator.next(self, timeout)
    866 if success:
    867     return value
--> 868 raise value

File ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/p38/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/pool.py:125, in worker()
    123 job, i, func, args, kwds = task
    124 try:
--> 125     result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
    126 except Exception as e:
    127     if wrap_exception and func is not _helper_reraises_exception:

File ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/p38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tsfresh/utilities/distribution.py:43, in _function_with_partly_reduce()
     41 kwargs = kwargs or {}
     42 results = (map_function(chunk, **kwargs) for chunk in chunk_list)
---> 43 results = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(results))
     44 return results

File ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/p38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tsfresh/utilities/distribution.py:42, in <genexpr>()
     25 """
     26 Small helper function to call a function (map_function)
     27 on a list of data chunks (chunk_list) and convert the results into
   (...)
     39 :rtype: list
     40 """
     41 kwargs = kwargs or {}
---> 42 results = (map_function(chunk, **kwargs) for chunk in chunk_list)
     43 results = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(results))
     44 return results

File ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/p38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tsfresh/feature_extraction/extraction.py:386, in _do_extraction_on_chunk()
    383 else:
    384     warnings.simplefilter("default")
--> 386 return list(_f())

File ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/p38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tsfresh/feature_extraction/extraction.py:364, in _f()
    361     x = data.values
    363 if getattr(func, "fctype", None) == "combiner":
--> 364     result = func(x, param=parameter_list)
    365 else:
    366     if parameter_list:

File ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/p38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tsfresh/feature_extraction/feature_calculators.py:2103, in friedrich_coefficients()
   2101 # calculate the current friedrich coefficients if they do not exist yet
   2102 if m not in calculated or r not in calculated[m]:
-> 2103     calculated[m][r] = _estimate_friedrich_coefficients(x, m, r)
   2105 try:
   2106     res["coeff_{}__m_{}__r_{}".format(coeff, m, r)] = calculated[m][r][coeff]

File ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/p38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tsfresh/feature_extraction/feature_calculators.py:152, in _estimate_friedrich_coefficients()
    150 df = pd.DataFrame({"signal": x[:-1], "delta": np.diff(x)})
    151 try:
--> 152     df["quantiles"] = pd.qcut(df.signal, r)
    153 except ValueError:
    154     return [np.NaN] * (m + 1)

File ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/p38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/tile.py:377, in qcut()
    375 x_np = np.asarray(x)
    376 x_np = x_np[~np.isnan(x_np)]
--> 377 bins = np.quantile(x_np, quantiles)
    379 fac, bins = _bins_to_cuts(
    380     x,
    381     bins,
   (...)
    386     duplicates=duplicates,
    387 )
    389 return _postprocess_for_cut(fac, bins, retbins, dtype, original)

File <__array_function__ internals>:180, in quantile()

File ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/p38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py:4412, in quantile()
   4410 if not _quantile_is_valid(q):
   4411     raise ValueError("Quantiles must be in the range [0, 1]")
-> 4412 return _quantile_unchecked(
   4413     a, q, axis, out, overwrite_input, method, keepdims)

File ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/p38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py:4424, in _quantile_unchecked()
   4416 def _quantile_unchecked(a,
   4417                         q,
   4418                         axis=None,
   (...)
   4421                         method="linear",
   4422                         keepdims=False):
   4423     """Assumes that q is in [0, 1], and is an ndarray"""
-> 4424     r, k = _ureduce(a,
   4425                     func=_quantile_ureduce_func,
   4426                     q=q,
   4427                     axis=axis,
   4428                     out=out,
   4429                     overwrite_input=overwrite_input,
   4430                     method=method)
   4431     if keepdims:
   4432         return r.reshape(q.shape + k)

File ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/p38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py:3725, in _ureduce()
   3722 else:
   3723     keepdim = (1,) * a.ndim
-> 3725 r = func(a, **kwargs)
   3726 return r, keepdim

File ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/p38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py:4593, in _quantile_ureduce_func()
   4591     else:
   4592         arr = a.copy()
-> 4593 result = _quantile(arr,
   4594                    quantiles=q,
   4595                    axis=axis,
   4596                    method=method,
   4597                    out=out)
   4598 return result

File ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/p38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py:4704, in _quantile()
   4702     slices_having_nans = None
   4703 # --- Get values from indexes
-> 4704 previous = np.take(arr, previous_indexes, axis=DATA_AXIS)
   4705 next = np.take(arr, next_indexes, axis=DATA_AXIS)
   4706 # --- Linear interpolation

File <__array_function__ internals>:180, in take()

File ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/p38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py:190, in take()
     93 @array_function_dispatch(_take_dispatcher)
     94 def take(a, indices, axis=None, out=None, mode='raise'):
     95     """
     96     Take elements from an array along an axis.
     97 
   (...)
    188            [5, 7]])
    189     """
--> 190     return _wrapfunc(a, 'take', indices, axis=axis, out=out, mode=mode)

File ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/p38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py:57, in _wrapfunc()
     54     return _wrapit(obj, method, *args, **kwds)
     56 try:
---> 57     return bound(*args, **kwds)
     58 except TypeError:
     59     # A TypeError occurs if the object does have such a method in its
     60     # class, but its signature is not identical to that of NumPy's. This
   (...)
     64     # Call _wrapit from within the except clause to ensure a potential
     65     # exception has a traceback chain.
     66     return _wrapit(obj, method, *args, **kwds)

IndexError: cannot do a non-empty take from an empty axes.
```

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: great suggestion @furas, added the complete error above.

Comment: I don't know this module but your code doesn't work on Linux Mint. But example from doc [extract_features](https://tsfresh.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/tsfresh.feature_extraction.html#tsfresh.feature_extraction.extraction.extract_features) works for me. Your code works for me only if I use `extract_features()` with `df` instead of `df_rolled`. It may suggests that it doesn't know how to work with this type of data which you get with `roll_time_series()`

Comment: Thanks @furas, yes, extract_feature work with df only for me as well. However results are mostly useful for classification/clustering type of ML where all of the timeseries need to be condensed down to a single number and be used a one single feature like the average of all time steps. In this case, I am trying to forecast along the time axis which needs rolling data like rolling averages and ... . So I kinda need to get this version to work. Thanks for point on Linux Mint, wondering if there are similarities there and with my MacOS.

Comment: @MeisamH I have started getting this error - any joy?